# Interprocess message queue in c?

Tags: c, process, queue, ipc

I'm writing a program in C using inter-process communication, specifically I'm trying to write a program using an inter-process message queue. The program should work like this:

- The command line accepts n-files (at least one). N-processes will be created as much as files.
- The n processes must send the contents of the file to a process called Receiver which will have the task of printing the messages received.

The problem is: not all the contents of the file are printed, even if the processes send the messages. Why ? Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define DIM_MSG 1024

#define TYPE_W 2

typedef struct
{
    long mtype;
    char eof;
    char mtext[DIM_MSG];
} msg;

void child_r(int coda, const char *file)
{

    FILE *r_stream;
    if ((r_stream = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("errore apertura file");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s:\n",file);

    msg messaggio;

    while (fgets(messaggio.mtext, DIM_MSG, r_stream) != NULL)
    {
      

        messaggio.mtype = TYPE_W;
        messaggio.eof = 0;
        if (msgsnd(coda, &messaggio, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long) , 0) == -1)
        {
            perror("msgsnd");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("\tMessage send: %s", messaggio.mtext);
    }

    strcpy(messaggio.mtext, "quit");
    messaggio.eof = 1;
    messaggio.mtype = TYPE_W;
    if (msgsnd(coda, &messaggio, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long) , 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(1);
    }

    fclose(r_stream);
    exit(0);
}

void child_f(int coda)
{
    msg messaggio;

    printf("\nReceiver\n");

    do
    {
        if (msgrcv(coda, &messaggio, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long), TYPE_W, 0) == -1)
        {
            perror("msgrcv");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (strcmp(messaggio.mtext, "quit") != 0)
        {
            printf("\tMessage rcv: %s ", messaggio.mtext);
        }

    } while (messaggio.eof != 1);

    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *file_name = NULL;
    struct stat sb;
    int child=0;


    int ds_coda;

    if(argc<1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Utilizzo %s <file-1> <file-2> <file-n>....",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if((ds_coda=msgget(IPC_PRIVATE,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0600))==-1)
    {
        perror("coda");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* analizza la command-line */
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            if ((stat(argv[i], &sb) == 0) && (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode)))
            {
                file_name = (char*)argv[i];
                child++;
                if(fork()==0)
                {
                    
                    child_r(ds_coda, file_name);
                }
            }
            else {
                perror(argv[i]);
                exit(1);
            }
    }
        
    if(child==0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Parametri non validi!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        // child_w
         sleep(1);
        child_f(ds_coda);
        
    }
    else wait(NULL);

    msgctl(ds_coda, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to review. Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried using `strace` to see what each process is doing?

Comment: Excuse me but I'm new in the industry, I don't know what strace is.
I've tried typing ipcs from the terminal to see if there are any messages still queued, but I can't see any.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. The main process needs to *loop* on `wait` before doing `IPC_RMID`. Otherwise, the sender processes will fail on `msgsnd` because the `ds_coda` is no longer valid. The main process has "raced" with the sender/receiver processes and removed the id with `IPC_RMID` *before* the other processes have completed.
2. *All* senders will set `messsaggio.eof` but the receiver stops after receiving the *first* one. It must know how many senders there are and wait until all have sent EOF. (i.e.) It must maintain a count.

---

Before I could debug this, I had to enhance the logging. So, I created `tscgetf`, `logopen`, and `logprt` to create *separate* logs for each process with timestamps.

When I was getting close, I added the `from` field to the message because the receiver was getting data but didn't know which process sent it. This helped diagnose the EOF issue.

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes.

By default, it will show the EOF issue (i.e. it will hang). To apply the fix for the EOF issue, compile with `-DFIXEOF`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIM_MSG 1024

#define TYPE_W 2

typedef struct {
    long mtype;
    int from;
    char eof;
    char mtext[DIM_MSG];
} msg;

int pididx;                         // linear process ID (0=main)
int child = 0;                      // number of spawned children
int ds_coda;

FILE *xflog;                        // debug log stream

#define logprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        fprintf(xflog,"[%.9f/%5.5d] ",tscgetf(),pididx); \
        fprintf(xflog,_fmt); \
        fflush(xflog); \
    } while (0)

double tsczero;

// tscget -- get timestamp
// RETURNS: elapsed seconds
double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    sec -= tsczero;

    return sec;
}

void
logopen(void)
{
    char logf[100];

    if (xflog != NULL)
        fclose(xflog);

    sprintf(logf,"log%3.3d",pididx);

    xflog = fopen(logf,"w");
    if (xflog == NULL) {
        perror(logf);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void
child_r(int coda, const char *file)
{
    FILE *r_stream;

    logopen();

    if ((r_stream = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("errore apertura file");
        exit(1);
    }

    logprt("child_r: reading %s\n", file);

    msg messaggio;

    messaggio.from = pididx;

    while (fgets(messaggio.mtext, DIM_MSG, r_stream) != NULL) {
        messaggio.mtype = TYPE_W;
        messaggio.eof = 0;
        if (msgsnd(coda, &messaggio, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long), 0) == -1) {
            perror("msgsnd");
            exit(1);
        }
        logprt("Message send: %s", messaggio.mtext);
    }

    strcpy(messaggio.mtext, "quit");
    messaggio.eof = 1;
    messaggio.mtype = TYPE_W;
#if 1
    strcpy(messaggio.mtext,"I_AM_EOF\n");
#endif
    if (msgsnd(coda, &messaggio, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long), 0) == -1) {
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(1);
    }
    logprt("Message EOF: %s", messaggio.mtext);

    fclose(r_stream);

    logprt("child_r: finished %s\n", file);

    fclose(xflog);
    exit(0);
}

void
child_f(int coda)
{
    msg messaggio;

    logopen();

    // NOTE: we are started last so the count we need to wait for is one less
    int waitcnt = pididx - 1;

    logprt("Receiver starting -- waitcnt=%d\n",waitcnt);

    while (1) {
        if (msgrcv(coda, &messaggio, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long), TYPE_W, 0) == -1) {
            perror("msgrcv");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (strcmp(messaggio.mtext, "quit") != 0) {
            logprt("Message rcv (from %d): %s",
                messaggio.from, messaggio.mtext);
        }

        if (messaggio.eof == 1) {
// NOTE/BUG: we can't stop after the first EOF message -- we must wait for all
// of them
#if ! FIXEOF
            logprt("got EOF\n");
            break;
#else
            logprt("got EOF -- waitcnt=%d\n",waitcnt);
            if (--waitcnt <= 0)
                break;
#endif
        }
    }

    logprt("child_f: complete\n");

    fclose(xflog);
    exit(0);
}

// start_rcv -- start receiver process
void
start_rcv(void)
{

    logprt("start_rcv:\n");

    child++;
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        pididx = child;
        // child_w
// NOTE/BUG: not necessary with other fixes
#if 0
        sleep(1);
#endif
        child_f(ds_coda);
    }

    logprt("start_rcv: pid=%d child=%d\n",pid,child);
}

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *file_name = NULL;
    struct stat sb;

    tsczero = tscgetf();

#if 1
    pid_t pid;
    setlinebuf(stdout);
    setlinebuf(stderr);
#endif

    logopen();

    if (argc < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Utilizzo %s <file-1> <file-2> <file-n>....", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((ds_coda = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0600)) == -1) {
        perror("coda");
        exit(1);
    }

// NOTE: early attempt to fix (receiver should start first) but didn't fix it
// and won't work because receiver needs to know the number of EOF messages to
// wait for
#if RCVEARLY
    start_rcv();
#endif

    /* analizza la command-line */
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if ((stat(argv[i], &sb) == 0) && (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode))) {
            file_name = (char *) argv[i];
            child++;
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0) {
                pididx = child;
                child_r(ds_coda, file_name);
            }
#if 1
            else {
                logprt("forked: pid=%d child=%d\n",pid,child);
            }
#endif
        }
        else {
            perror(argv[i]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (child == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Parametri non validi!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

// NOTE/FIX: main process must wait for _all_ children to complete before
// doing IPC_RMID
#if 1
#if ! RCVEARLY
    start_rcv();
#endif

    while (1) {
        pid_t pid = wait(NULL);
        logprt("waitfor: %d child=%d\n",pid,child);
        if (pid <= 0)
            break;
        --child;
    }
#endif

    msgctl(ds_coda, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    fclose(xflog);

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

Comment: I don't understando your code. I test it,but there is not any print :(

Comment: @ValentinoFabrisValenti The program will put the debug output in various `log*` files. The main thread will output to `log000`. If you gave the program two args (e.g.) `./myprogram abc.txt def.txt`, then you would see `log001` for the process reading `abc.txt`, `log002` for the process reading `def.txt` and `log003` for the receiver that does `msgrcv`